# Check if element exists in list using re

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I check element exists in list using `re` method in efficient way?

```
list = ['abc', 'efg','xyz:3+1']
a = "efg"
if a in list:
    print "element exist"
else:
    print "element not exist"


Expected Output:element exist


if a = "123"
Expected output: element not exist
if a = "xyz"
Expected output: element not exist
```

What i have to achieve is when `a` is xyz:number + number, then print "element exists".

```
if a = "xyz:10 + 5" 
Expected Output:element exist
if a = "xyz:3 + 1" 
Expected Output:element exist
if a = "xyz:10 + " 
Expected Output:element not exist
if a = "xyz:10" 
Expected Output:element not exist
```

Comment: `\d` is the regex pattern for a single digit.  Work up from there.

Comment: `re.match(r'xyz:\d+ \+ \d+', 'xyz:10 + 5')`

Comment: Thanks, I have used re now

Answer (score 0):

Use re as follows:

```
import re
alist = ['abc', 'efg', 'xyz:3+1']
patt = re.compile(r'xyz:\s*\d+\s*\+\s*\d+\s*$')

def check_exist(e, alist, patt=patt):
    if e in alist:
        return "element exist"
    if patt.match(e):
        t = [i for i in alist if patt.match(i)]
        return "similar elements found: {}".format(t)
    return "element not exist"

a = "efg"
print(check_exist(a, alist))
a = "xyz:10 + 5"
print(check_exist(a, alist))
```

Output:

```
element exist
similar elements found: ['xyz:3+1']
```